How to get Sharepoint Online document file using C#
It was not working:
Uri endpointUri = new Uri(webUrl + "/\_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + webRelativeUrl + "/" + documentLibName + "/" + fileName + "')/$value");
try{
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpointUri);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error
using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()){
using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(path + fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate | FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)){
await contentStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}
}
Console.WriteLine("File downloaded successfully.");
}catch (HttpRequestException ex){
Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading file: {ex.Message}");
}

In this line it fails.
Error :
ystem.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) FORBIDDEN.
  Source=System.Net.Requests
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in E:\LeaveManagement\Sharepoint\Program.cs:line 34

I am the owner of my Sharepoint Team why its not working

Need to solve this issue in high priority please

Nobody's going to see this comment, nor respond faster. The best way to get a faster answer is to write a good, readable question. Both the code and errors should be readable. Besides, did you check the error? It says (403) FORBIDDEN.. You tried to download a file anonymously

How can I retrieve the data not download , because I am using share point online private group and I am the owner of that group
why I am not performing the operation.

Edit the question so it's readable. Then read what you wrote - there are no credentials anywhere. As far as the server is concerned you aren't any user. retrieve the data not download is a contradiction. Retrieving means downloading, even if you don't save the file to disk

I'll do and paste into another site

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78267653/23314104  please give me a answer on this

Posting the same question twice will only get downvotes. Read the documentation and pass the correct credentials. You still haven't cleaned up this question.

How to connect Sharepoint online document data using C# .
Give me reference please.
